# Binding widget properties to Python variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, binding, pyqt, pyqt5

was trying to understand https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Binding%20widget%20properties%20to%20Python%20variables :

**"Binding widget properties to Python variables"**

down below my modified code that took a while to me, but kind of visualize better what `bind`, example code, here,  does:

```
def bind(objectName, propertyName, type):

    def getter(self):
        return type(self.findChild(QObject, objectName).property(propertyName).toPyObject())
    
    def setter(self, value):
        self.findChild(QObject, objectName).setProperty(propertyName, QVariant(value))
    
    return property(getter, setter)
```

my complete code is:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLineEdit, QTextEdit, QCheckBox, QFormLayout, QPushButton

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


def bind(objectName, propertyName, type):

    def getter(self):
        return type(self.findChild(QObject, objectName).property(propertyName).toPyObject())
    
    def setter(self, value):
        self.findChild(QObject, objectName).setProperty(propertyName, QVariant(value))
    
    return property(getter, setter)

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
    
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.nameEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.nameEdit.setObjectName("nameEdit")
        self.addressEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.addressEdit.setObjectName("addressEdit")
        self.contactCheckBox = QCheckBox()
        self.contactCheckBox.setObjectName("contactCheckBox")
        self.button_1 = QPushButton('press me !!!')
        self.button_1.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_1_Pressed)
        
        self.button_2 = QPushButton('press me !!! second')
        self.button_2.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_2_Pressed)
        

        self.layout = QFormLayout(self)
        self.layout.addRow(self.tr("Name:"), self.nameEdit)
        self.layout.addRow(self.tr("Address:"), self.addressEdit)
        self.layout.addRow(self.tr("Receive extra information:"), self.contactCheckBox)
        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button_1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button_2)
        
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        
        self.name = bind('nameEdit', 'text', str)
        self.address = bind("addressEdit", "plainText", str)
        self.contact = bind("contactCheckBox", "checked", bool)
            
    def pushButton_1_Pressed(self):
        
        print(self.nameEdit.text())
        
        print(self.addressEdit.toPlainText())
        
        print(self.contactCheckBox.isChecked())
        
    def pushButton_2_Pressed(self):

        self.nameEdit.setText('pippo')
        
        
        self.addressEdit.clear()
        self.addressEdit.insertPlainText('papero')
        
        self.contactCheckBox.setChecked(True)
        
        print(self.nameEdit.text())
        
        print(self.addressEdit.toPlainText())
        
        print(self.contactCheckBox.isChecked())

    


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

after you insert text into a `QLineEdit` or `QTextEdit` or check a `QCheckBox` widget
you can print the variables defined by `bind` and pressing the second button you change the variable values and the text/values of the widgets at the same time (got some insight from [Binding a PyQT/PySide widget to a local variable in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992849/binding-a-pyqt-pyside-widget-to-a-local-variable-in-python).

since the inners of Python and PyQt5 are to hard to me right know, is about a dumb-proof descriprion about how `bind` works in the code on the three widgets.

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: Are you asking how does that "bind" work? Also, your code is not valid: 1. you're trying to use the binding as instance attribute, but they are *class* attributes (look at the indentation level of those lines in the original post of the first link); 2. that code is for PyQt4, and in PyQt5 by default Qt properties are returned already converted to python objects, so remove `.toPyObject()` in the getter and change `QVariant(value)` to `value` in the setter; 3. you're *not* using those bindings at all (if you were, your program would crash due to the above issues).

Comment: @eyllanesc, Hi its been a while... first of all why print(self.name) gives <property object at 0x7f7c15d1a680> ? Actually how are properties related to the widgets

Comment: @musicamante, thanks dude. I'll try to edit it for PyQt5 and see if able to manage the class variable bit, any link to 'Binding widget properties to Python variables' for PyQt5

Comment: @musicamante, sorry to bother, I can get all QLineEdit proprierties from here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#properties (Qt documentation). How can I get them from Python ?

Comment: I mean I can use for i in QLineEdit.__dict__.items() :
    print(i) but wich ones are properties and which are not ?

Comment: @pippo1980 are you asking how to get the list of *all* properties? As far as I know, it's not possible to get it from the class, but only from one of its instances, which can be achieved through their [QMetaObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html): `lineEdit = QLineEdit()` `meta = lineEdit.metaObject()` `for p in range(meta.propertyCount()):` `property = meta.property(p)`, which returns a [QMetaProperty](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaproperty.html) for each property defined for that class.

Comment: Thanks wasn’t able to distinguish between attributes and attributes-properties

Comment: got it  print(p , '  :  ',property.name())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article you are referring to tries to implement the [`python properties`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) using the QObjects properties.

Since it is a property it should not be declared within the class but at the method level as class attribute. On the other hand, the code must be updated since it is written for PyQt4 where the conversion between objects from python to Qt was not implicit, considering the above, the solution is:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QWidget,
    QLineEdit,
    QTextEdit,
    QCheckBox,
    QFormLayout,
    QPushButton,
)


def bind(objectName, propertyName):
    def getter(self):
        return self.findChild(QObject, objectName).property(propertyName)

    def setter(self, value):
        self.findChild(QObject, objectName).setProperty(propertyName, value)

    return property(getter, setter)


class Window(QWidget):
    name = bind("nameEdit", "text")
    address = bind("addressEdit", "plainText")
    contact = bind("contactCheckBox", "checked")

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.nameEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.nameEdit.setObjectName("nameEdit")
        self.addressEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.addressEdit.setObjectName("addressEdit")
        self.contactCheckBox = QCheckBox()
        self.contactCheckBox.setObjectName("contactCheckBox")
        self.button_1 = QPushButton("press me !!!")
        self.button_1.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_1_Pressed)

        self.button_2 = QPushButton("press me !!! second")
        self.button_2.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_2_Pressed)

        layout = QFormLayout(self)
        layout.addRow(self.tr("Name:"), self.nameEdit)
        layout.addRow(self.tr("Address:"), self.addressEdit)
        layout.addRow(self.tr("Receive extra information:"), self.contactCheckBox)

        layout.addWidget(self.button_1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button_2)

    def pushButton_1_Pressed(self):
        print(self.name)
        print(self.address)
        print(self.contact)

    def pushButton_2_Pressed(self):
        self.name = "pippo"
        self.address = ""
        self.address += "papero"
        self.contact = True
        print(self.address)
        print(self.contact)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: hi any hint about how to understand python properties and widget properties ?

Comment: @pippo1980 About python properties read the link of my post and about Qt properties read the official docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html

Comment: sorry didnt get the link, now I see it, thanks. Is PyQt5 officially on github or Do I need to download from riverbank ?

Comment: @pippo1980 PyQt is not officially on github (but there are unofficial repositories), and you should install it using pip anyway.

Comment: okeydokey , cheers again

Comment: @pippo1980 Even if it were in GH I don't think it would be useful to you since there is almost nothing written in python, most of them are .sip files. PyQt5 only exposes Qt5 without adding any magic to it. You can download the source code and check it: https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/#files