Controlling height of QMenuBar (hideable menu bar) in PyQt5?
I wanted a hideable menu bar in PyQt5, and I found this example:

https://github.com/yjg30737/pyqt-hidable-menubar

My platform is:
$ uname -s
MINGW64_NT-10.0-19045

$ python3 --version
Python 3.11.8

$ pacman -Q mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pyqt5
mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pyqt5 5.15.10-2

The example HidableMenuBar actually works - except for one thing that worries me: I get this error/warning:
QPropertyAnimation: you're trying to animate the non-writable property height of your QObject

And indeed, in code https://github.com/yjg30737/pyqt-hidable-menubar/blob/main/pyqt_hidable_menubar/hidableMenuBar.py we have:
class HidableMenuBar(QMenuBar):
# ...
    def __initUi(self):
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        # ...
        self.setCornerWidget(self.__showToggleBtn)

        height = self.sizeHint().height()

        self.__menuAnimation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"height")
        self.__menuAnimation.valueChanged.connect(self.setFixedHeight)

        self.__menuAnimation.setStartValue(height)
        self.__menuAnimation.setDuration(200)  # default duration
        self.__menuAnimation.setEndValue(1)  # default end value

    def __showMenu(self):
        self.__menuAnimation.setDirection(QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
        self.__menuAnimation.start()
        self.__hide_flag = False
        self.hideSignal.emit(self.__hide_flag)

    def __hideMenu(self):
        self.__menuAnimation.setDirection(QAbstractAnimation.Forward)
        self.__menuAnimation.start()
        self.__hide_flag = True
        self.hideSignal.emit(self.__hide_flag)

    def enterEvent(self, e):
        if self.__hide_flag:
            self.__showMenu()
        return super().enterEvent(e)

    def event(self, e):
        if int(e.type()) == 76: # QEvent.LayoutRequest, see https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/PyQt/qevent.html
            height = self.sizeHint().height()
            self.__menuAnimation.setStartValue(height)
        return super().event(e)

So indeed, it tries to animate on height property - the idea seems to be to use .setEndValue(1) for height to make the menubar 1 pixel high when collapsed, so a mouseover/Enter on it would be detected, and the menubar can expand again
But - what confuses me, is how is it possible at all that this class manages to collapse and expand the menubar, if the height property is not writable?
This tells me that this (1-pixel QMenuBar height) is not really a long-term solution (even if it worksforme now), so I'd like to find a proper implementation ...
I found this discussion, related to "QPropertyAnimation: you're trying to animate the non-writable property ": Simple animation not working | Qt Forum

[...] The error message is quite clear: you cannot change the property width via the property system of QObject. If you look at "QWidget's property width":http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#width-prop you will see, that there is only a getter, not a setter.
[...] Thanks! This one works perfect ... QPropertyAnimation(this,"geometry");

So, there they decided to work with geometry property instead, and is it settable/writable, it apparently works for their case ...
However, for QMenuBar it is said https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenubar.html

There is no need to lay out a menu bar. It automatically sets its own geometry to the top of the parent widget and changes it appropriately whenever the parent is resized.

And indeed: if I try retrieving self.geometry() in the class constructor, I get e.g. (0, 0, 640, 480) which looks like a size of the parent window - and I've also tried changing the height explicitly in the geometry setting, and it does not seem to make a difference.
So, what options do I have to make a hideable menubar in PyQt5 properly? that is:

it should be possible to "close" / hide the menubar like in the example (with a close button - no problem with that);
it should be possible to "open" the menubar again by moving / hovering the mouse close to the top of the window (although not sure how it can be implemented without a 1-pixel height, now that we see we cannot really change the QMenuBar height)?
I should not get a warning/error


The resizing works because you also connected the setFixedHeight() slot, while a property animation normally doesn't require doing that, as long as the property is writable, which is not the case of height. The geometry you're seeing is the default for newly created widgets (except when created as child widgets, which then is 100x30). Trying to manually set the menubar geometry during initialization is pointless, since it would be overridden by the main window layout once the first resize event is received (normally, right before showing).

Many thanks for the great explanation, @musicamante - ultimately I used your comment https://stackoverflow.com/q/69529864#comment122924518_69529864 to iterate through all properties, and find those that are isWritable and typeName() == "int" or "double" - it turns out that maximumHeight is writeable, so if I just replace "height" with it in with self.__menuAnimation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"maximumHeight"), then all seems to work, without a warning. Thanks again!

You don't need to iterate and do all that. Just check the documentation: every QObject based class normally has a "properties" section (for instance, QWidget properties) which are obviously inherited by subclasses. Each property always has a getter function, if it's writable then it also has a related setter function. Note that the maximum size only ensures that the widget cannot be larger than defined, but this doesn't automatically change the size if the hint and policy of the widget don't need more. That's why it's preferable to use fixed sizes.
